# MVVM - Mutliple classes in different projects for one control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this little piece of code right here. What I want to achieve is that the Command property is binded to Class 1 while the IsEnabled property is binded to Class 2.

```
<MenuItem Header="A_nmelden..." Command="{Binding ShowLoginCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static UserManagementAdapter.LogOnIsEnabled}}"/>
```

But there seems to be a problem when trying to access UserManagmentAdapter. The class UserManagmentAdapter is not in the same project as the project that contains this MenuItem control. So I am getting the error

> "UserManagmentAdapter" is not supported in a Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF) project

My properties that I want to access:

```
private bool logOnIsEnabled;
public bool LogOnIsEnabled
{
    get { return this.logOnIsEnabled; }
    set { this.logOnIsEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged("LogOnIsEnabled"); }
}

private bool logOffIsEnabled;
public bool LogOffIsEnabled
{
    get { return this.logOffIsEnabled; }
    set { this.logOffIsEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged("LogOffIsEnabled"); }
}
```

My Class 2:

```
namespace ZF.UserManagement
{
    [ExportAdapter(nameof(UserManagementAdapter))]
    public class UserManagementAdapter : AdapterBase, IMultiValueConverter
    {...}
}
```

I hope I have made it clear enough. 
Anyone knows how to access UserManagmentAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a namespace declaration in your XAML:

```
<MenuItem xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace;assembly=YourAssembly" 
          Header="A_nmelden..." Command="{Binding ShowLoginCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static local:UserManagmentAdapter.LogOnIsEnabled}}"/>
```

...where "YourNamespace" is the namespace in which the `UserManagmentAdapter` class is defined and "YourAssembly" is the name of the assembly.

If the `UserManagmentAdapter` class is defined in your WPF application project, i.e. not in a separate assembly, you should remove the `;assembly=YourAssembly` part:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ZF.UserManagement"
```

Comment: I made this but for some reason it cant find "LogOnIsEnabled". Any idea what causes this?
`<MenuItem Header="A_nmelden..." xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ZF.UserManagement;assembly=ZF.ZMS4.Components" Command="{Binding ShowLoginCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static local:UserManagmentAdapter.LogOnIsEnabled}}"/>
`

Comment: Is it a property of the UserManagmentAdapter class? Is the class defined in a separate assembly?

Comment: Yes it is a public property and the class is in another project

Comment: Try to move the namespace declaration to the parent window or something and make sure that you have spelled the names correctly. Please provide full repo if you need any further help. I guess you have already tried to build the project.

Comment: What is weird is that Visual Studio seems to find LogOnIsEnabled (right click -> go to definition is working). But as soon as I start debugging I get an error

Comment: Could you at least post the definition of your class?

Comment: `public class UserManagementAdapter : AdapterBase, IMultiValueConverter`
in namespace ZF.UserManagement

Comment: Edit your question...and include the properties as well.

Comment: Your property isn't static...?

Comment: No but if I do, how do I use OnPropertyChanged with static members?

Comment: The point is that you can't use x:Static to bind to a non-static property...You need to create an instance of your class and bind to this. But that's another story really. Please don't ask additional questions in the comments field. Ask another question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `Class1` and `Class2` properties of your ViewModel and then access the properties in XAML:

**Code behind**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Class1 class1 { get; set; }
    public Class2 class2 { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<MenuItem Header="A_nmelden..." Command="{Binding class1.ShowLoginCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding class2.LogOnIsEnabled}"/>
```